# How to make css icon font to show blank square when page is loading?

Tags: css, icons

I see in many websites that showing the blank square icons on page loading, then after the page has loaded properly, the actual icons are shown.

So I wonder how to make the icons work like that?

I tried to create a simple arrow icon in a .woff format, then load in using css like:

```
.my-icon {
    font-family: 'my-custom-icon';
    content: 'A';
}
```

The arrow is showing correctly. However, on page loading, its still showing as `A` character

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use background or make a layer in behind the actual icons. Try to use `z-index: -1`

```
.my-icon:after {        
    font-family: 'my-custom-icon';
    content: 'A';
    z-index: -1;
}
```